# Binding a listview within a user control programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, user-controls

I am currently trying to programmatically bind a listview with a user control. i have a dataset which contains a table that consists of 2 columns (`id`, `regrading`). I am trying to add the `regarding` column to the listview and the `SelectedValuePath` as the `id`.

tried with grid view, however just would like a simple listview as this user control is a custom ComboBox.

```
GridView myGridView = new GridView();
myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = true;
GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("id");        
gvc1.Width = 10;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);
GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("regarding");
gvc2.Width = 100;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc2);
regarding.DropDownContents.View = myGridView;
DataSet regardingData = db.GetRegarding();
regarding.DropDownContents.ItemsSource = regardingData.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @h.b. elaborate? the user control is used in other places, can i access the listview from the xaml user control?

Comment: You are not supposed to access controls within other controls, but manipulate the data that is bound to them or (dependency) properties that are explicitly exposed by the control to the outside. The question was about why you would do the binding in code, that usually is unnecessary and ugly.